# Computing the value of text box to another

Tags: jquery

if you click add item it shows 3 text box. If you input an amount in expense cost it must be shown in Overall Cost(or the sum of all expenses I have entered), Then if I will input an amount in Acquisition Cost , the Overall cost must show the sum of Expense Cost and Acquisition Cost, automatically. But my problem is, If I now input something in Acquisition, The Overall Cost becomes Zero (0).

Here is the example: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6jga8/14/)

```
var nitem =0; 
var ntotal = 0;

        $(document).on('change', '.expense_cost', function() { 
            ntotal = 0;
                $('.expense_cost').each(function(){ 
                    if($(this).val() != ""){
                        ntotal += parseFloat($(this).val()); 
                        }
                    }); 
                $('#total').val(ntotal); 
            }); 

        $('.btn').click(function() { 
            nitem++; 
                $('#wrapper').before('<div id="div' + nitem + '" class="inputwrap">' +
                    '<input class="expense_name" placeholder="Expense Name" id="' + nitem + '"/>' +
                    '<input class="expense_desc" placeholder="Expense Description" id="' + nitem + '"/>' +
                    '<input class="expense_cost" placeholder="Expense Cost" id="' + nitem + '"/><br><br>' +
                    '</div>');  
                }); 

        $('.btn2').click(function() {           
            ntotal = $('#total').val(); 
                $("#div" + nitem + " .expense_cost").each(function(){               
                    if($(this).val() != ""){
                        ntotal -= parseFloat($(this).val()); 
                        }
                    }); 

                    $("#div" + nitem ).remove();
                        nitem--; 
                    $('#total').val(ntotal); }); 




        var textbox = $("#txtTaxPercent");
        var ResultTextbox = $("#txtfctTaxValue");
        var PriceTextbox = $("#txtPurePrice");
        var pricetotal = $("#total");
            $([textbox[0], PriceTextbox[0]]).bind("change keyup keydown paste", function(e) {
                var Result;
                Result = (parseFloat(textbox.val()) / 100) * parseInt(PriceTextbox.val());
                pricetotal.val(Result);
                ResultTextbox.val(Result);  

            });
```

Comment: Is there anyway you could explain this a little better? I don't seem to understand what the problem is, maybe I'm just slow

Comment: Personally, I'm lost. I played with the fiddle and I don't even understand what its supposed to do.

Comment: fiddle is good. you can tell what you want based on your fiddle. Need to clear your requirement.

Comment: if you click add item it shows 3 text box. If you input an amount in expense cost it must be shown in Overall Cost(or the sum of all expenses I have entered), Then if I will input an amount in Acquisition Cost , the Overall cost must show the sum of Expense Cost and Acquisition Cost, automatically. But my problem is, If I now input something in Acquisition, The Overall Cost becomes Zero (0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen your code and found some problems. I have fixed most of the problems now it's working. I have changed this and some others.

```
     $([textbox[0], PriceTextbox[0]]).bind("keyup paste", function(e) {
                $("#txtfctTaxValue").val(0);
                var Result;

                totalItemExpence();
                if(PriceTextbox.val()!=="" ){
                    Result = (parseFloat(textbox.val()) / 100) * parseInt(PriceTextbox.val());
                }
                else{
                    Result = 0;
                }
                Result = parseFloat( Result) + ntotal;
                pricetotal.val(Result);
                ResultTextbox.val(Result);  

            });
```

You didn't concern about the total expense in items during calculate the overall cast on change of acquisition cost. And also try to use textbox value checking the value is null or empty or not otherwise you will get NAN in your arithmatic operation. Have a look http://jsfiddle.net/hannnan/6jga8/15/

Comment: Ok. It's my pleasure. And No need to thanks. You can accept my answer by flag this answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks sir. But there's quite problem on my acquisition and marginal if you going to try your code, if you add a text box and add an amount then move to acquisition and margin the overall cost is not working unless you should type another amount to work it well.

Comment: $([textbox[0], PriceTextbox[0]]).bind("change keyup paste",function()};

just add the change event in there.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hannnan/6jga8/16/
I think it's working fine. I have show you how to do it.. You can apply and check in every possible way to make sure everything working fine.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you in this aspect. Because I am not a php developer. But of course you can. I think you will get your answer if you do some google search.